# Set boolean from outside Thread, inside the Thread-run

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable, final

I've got a boolean outside the Thread. Then I use a method that requires a Thread around it that returns a boolean. How can I set the boolean outside the thread with the returned boolean?

Code:

```
// Handle Automatic E-Mail Sending in a new Thread
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Since we want to display a Toast from within a different Thread,
        // we need to use the runOnUiThread to display it
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(ChecklistActivity.cActivity, D.T_SENDING_EMAIL, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        /*TODO: emailSuccessfullySent = */EMailSender.SendEmail();
    }
}).start();
```

I've read somewhere I could do it with a final array like so:

```
final boolean[] array = new boolean[1];
// Handle Automatic E-Mail Sending in a new Thread
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Since we want to display a Toast from within a different Thread,
        // we need to use the runOnUiThread to display it
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(ChecklistActivity.cActivity, D.T_SENDING_EMAIL, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        array[0] = EMailSender.SendEmail();
    }
}).start();
emailSuccessfullySent = array[0];
```

But I find this rather odd. Is this the generally accepted way to set a value from within a Thread, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using a `Callable` (https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/get_netbeans_6?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+corejavatechtips+(Core+Java+Technologies+Tech+Tips)) to return a value from a thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It requires a little more overhead, but the best way to approach this problem in Android is to use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). A `Handler` is a structure which you can use to receive messages from multiple threads and execute code on the thread the `Handler` is defined in. By overriding the `handleMessage(Message msg)` method and defining a few constants, you can send messages from any thread and have them be handled in your UI thread.

Code:

```
public boolean variable = false;
private class MyHandler extends Handler {
    public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 1;
    public static final int THREAD_RETURN = 2;

    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        if(msg.what == MESSAGE_TOAST){
            Toast.makeText(msg.getData().getString("toast"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if(msg.what == THREAD_RETURN){
            variable = msg.getData().getBoolean("returnValue");
        }
    }
}
public MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();
```

This would make your thread look like this:

```
// Handle Automatic E-Mail Sending in a new Thread
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.setString("toast","I want to display this message");
        Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(MyHandler.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        msg.setData(bundle);
        msg.sendToTarget();
        bundle.setBoolean("returnValue", EMailSender.SendEmail());
        msg = handler.obtainMessage(MyHandler.THREAD_RETURN);
        msg.setData(bundle);
        msg.sendToTarget();
   }
}).start();
```

It's a little confusing when you start using `Handler`s, but once you get to know them, they are easy and very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about setting the value of a non-`synchronized` variable inside a `Thread`. Since your `boolean` is declared "outside" the scope of your `Thread`, what you have done is a perfectly acceptable way of doing it. The point here is the scope of the `boolean`. You don't need to use an array, though. And the `final` qualifier is simply because variables declared outside the scope of an inner class cannot be accessed if they are not `final`.